# Data Visualization: How to represent kWh usage by year against average temperature

Tags: excel, charts, google-sheets, data-visualization

Just for fun, I want to chart my monthly household power consumption year-over-year.  However, I wish to include some reference to monthly temperature so I can determine if my home or behavior is improving, worsening, or holding steady in regards to kWh usage.

The data I am working with:

`+----------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+-----------+------------+
|  Month   | # Days | kWh Usage | Daily kWh Avg. | Avg. Low | Avg. High | Avg. Temp. |
+----------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| Mar 2015 |     32 |      1048 |             33 |       40 |        60 |         50 |
| Feb 2015 |     29 |      1156 |             40 |       32 |        54 |         43 |
| Jan 2015 |     33 |      1143 |             35 |       38 |        57 |         47 |
| Dec 2014 |     30 |       887 |             30 |       39 |        61 |         50 |
| Nov 2014 |     29 |       645 |             22 |       45 |        67 |         56 |
| Oct 2014 |     29 |       598 |             21 |       60 |        78 |         69 |
| Sep 2014 |     32 |       893 |             28 |       70 |        85 |         77 |
| Aug 2014 |     30 |       965 |             32 |       72 |        87 |         79 |
| Jul 2014 |     29 |       784 |             27 |       72 |        87 |         79 |
| Jun 2014 |     32 |      1018 |             32 |       69 |        87 |         78 |
| May 2014 |     30 |       702 |             23 |       63 |        82 |         72 |
| Apr 2014 |     33 |       722 |             22 |       50 |        71 |         60 |
| Mar 2014 |     29 |       830 |             29 |       41 |        62 |         52 |
| Feb 2014 |     28 |      1197 |             43 |       32 |        52 |         42 |
| Jan 2014 |     33 |      1100 |             33 |       38 |        59 |         49 |
| Dec 2013 |     30 |       856 |             29 |       40 |        63 |         51 |
| Nov 2013 |     33 |       686 |             21 |       48 |        70 |         59 |
| Oct 2013 |     30 |       527 |             18 |       61 |        77 |         69 |
| Sep 2013 |     30 |       817 |             27 |       69 |        86 |         77 |
| Aug 2013 |     28 |       991 |             35 |       72 |        86 |         79 |
| Jul 2013 |     31 |       993 |             32 |       73 |        86 |         79 |
| Jun 2013 |     30 |       847 |             28 |       66 |        83 |         74 |
| May 2013 |     29 |       605 |             21 |       59 |        76 |         67 |
| Apr 2013 |     34 |       791 |             23 |       47 |        66 |         57 |
+----------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------+-----------+------------+`

I started with a column chart easily comparing month-to-month values:

[image: Month-to-Month Usage Column Chart]

I envisioned a nice background area or line graph mapped to a secondary (right) vertical axis showing the high/low ranges but realized that would be problematic with the multi-year groupings.

It would be easy with one single year:

[image: 2014 kWh Usage with Temperatures]

**I am curious to know if anyone can recommend a way of combining all the yearly data into a single chart with temperature comparisons?**

Is there some ratio I could use that could effectively relate the kWh usage to average temperature... or some other display technique I am overlooking... or am I stuck with one chart per year?

Comment: The answer below was sufficient for my immediate needs, however, I posted the same question on stats.stackexhange and received an extremely detailed answer.  I highly recommend reading it for a better understanding of the statistics and data analysis involve:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148166/74048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon what would be useful is to get an equation determining the relationship between average temperature against KWh used daily. This will let you predict in future how close you're fitting this relationship (and also look retrospectively back at which months were anomalies).

I knocked up a quick graph and used the excel 'add polynomial equation' function which gave:

[image]

Interesting, because I expected a more linear relationship - the colder it gets, the more electricity you use to heat. But maybe you're using air con in the summer months heavily?

Anyway you can now use

```
Predicted daily usage = 0.0488*(average temp^2) - 6.2408(average temp) + 219.95
```

which is kind of your 'average' usage vs temperature relationship, to compare against specific months and figure if you're above or below. So in August 2013, you used more electricity than you should. July 2014, you were well under.

[image]

Not sure this is exactly what you asked, but I think it's what I'd want to know.

More interesting than my work :P Cheers for the distraction.

Comment: Using your suggestion I was able to combine all the information I originally wanted in a single chart [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hLqPc5E82pZa-lmYu0GTcvQ-fd8X9LrgO5gCSPLG2Vo/edit?usp=sharing]